# Visual studio C # y un PLC

Tags: c#

¿Cómo enviaría la información a un registro específico del PLC desde C# y cómo identificar ese Registro?

Estoy uzando la librería EASYbodbus

Me está dando un error me gustaría que me ayudaran a que se refiere:

```
EasyModbus.Exceptions.FunctionCodeNotSupportedException:
'Function code not supported by master'
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using EasyModbus;

namespace comunicacion_tcp
{
    class Program
    {
        private string IpAddress = "192.168.178.111";
        private int port = 502;
        private ushort startAddres = 0;
        private ushort quantity = 2;
        private ModbusClient modbustcp;
        public Program()
        {
            modbustcp = new ModbusClient(IpAddress, port);
            modbustcp.Connect();
            int[] response = modbustcp.ReadInputRegisters(startAddres, quantity);
            modbustcp.Disconnect();
            Console.WriteLine("value of input register 1" + response[0].ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("value of input register 2" + response[1].ToString());
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program _program = new Program();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da error?

Comment: Esto quizás te sea de utilidad: http://modbus.org/docs/PI_MBUS_300.pdf

Comment: Esta línea de error es que aparece este mensaje.  
int[] response = modbustcp.ReadInputRegisters(startAddres, quantity);

Comment: Sucede que le estás enviando un `0` y según la documentación, debería ser otra cosa: http://dghcorp.com/modbus/modbusrtu04.asp y   http://www.simplymodbus.ca/FC04.htm

Comment: esto probablemente te sirva: http://easymodbustcp.net/crc-calculation-for-modbus-rtu